# Calling a virtual function through a pointer using async in c++

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I'm new to multi-threading and have limited knowledge in programming. I want to use async function in c++ to call a virtual function. Snippets of the code are given below. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
class Binary_Genome: public Individual  
{  
public:    
    std::string evaluate_fitness();  
}

class Individual
{
public:
     virtual std::string evaluate_fitness()=0;
}

int main()
{
  std::string w_list;
  Individual* current_ind;

  //Skipped some code here

  std::future<std::string> future_strs;
  future_strs = std::async(current_ind->evaluate_fitness);  //Complier does not understand this line.
  w_list = future_strs.get();

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation error:

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function
```

I understand std::async(current_ind->evaluate_fitness) is incorrect syntax. However, I don't know what the correct syntax is. The code works perfectly without async (w_list = current_ind->evaluate_fitness()). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if it were to compile, you would get memory error since `Individual* current_ind;` doesn't initialize the pointer. currently it points to garbage memory address.

yo ucan use pointers to objects in `std::async` liek that:

```
Object obj;
Object* pointer = &obj;
auto fut = std::async([pointer]{  return pointer->returnSomthing(); });
```

make sure that `obj` is alive as long as the async function runs. `std::shared_ptr` is extremly suitable for that.

Comment: I felt compelled to downvote you for presenting `new` at all.

Comment: How can I use this pointer?